# CLIPS: How to print special characters and letters like "ñ"?

Tags: clips, expert-system

I'm coding a spanish expert system, so I have to print words with letters "ñ" or "á,é,í" or "¿" and cannot figure it out yet, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Are you able to type them on your keyboard? If so, printing `"niño"` should work..!

Comment: I can type them, printing "niño" is like "NIÃ‘O" and "niÃ±o".

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an issue with your terminal. Where are you running your programs? The best solution might be to search google for issues specific to your coding environment. (For example, I'm on macOS, my terminal has no issues with this.)

[image]

Also, if you just want a quick solution, most languages have support for Unicode-encoded strings. For example, here's how you would do it in Python (note, ñ is 361 in octal Unicode):

```py
>>> print('ni\361o')
niño
```

However, if your issue persists I would recommend you try searching for users who had similar problems *who also use your coding environment*. I hope you're able to find a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 6.3, CLIPS provides internal support for UTF-8 strings. So if you're using a text editor that supports UTF-8 encodings you can write programs with languages using diacritical marks (such as Spanish), other non-Latin characters sets with a small alphabet (such as Russia), and languages with complex glyphs (such as Japanese):

```
(deffacts hello
   (hello "Hello World")
   (hello "Привет мир")
   (hello "مرحبا العالم")
   (hello "你好世界")
   (hello "ハローワールド")
   (hello "여러분, 안녕하세요")
   (hello "Olá Mundo"))

(defrule hello
   (hello ?h)
   =>
   (printout t ?h crlf))
```

Input and output of these characters sets depends on the environment in which CLIPS is run. If you run CLIPS as a terminal application on macOS or Linux, UTF-8 is supported. The macOS IDE for CLIPS 6.3 and 6.4 support UTF-8.
CLIPSJNI, http://www.clipsrules.net/CLIPSJNI.html, also demonstrates how you can embed CLIPS in an environment supporting UTF-8 (in this case Java) to take advantage of CLIPS internal support of UTF-8.

The Windows IDE for CLIPS 6.3 does not support UTF-8 I/O. It uses older Win32 APIs and was not designed with unicode support in mind. The Windows IDE for CLIPS 6.4 uses the modern .NET frameworks which support UTF-8 I/O.

By default, Windows Command Prompt does not provide support for UTF-8 I/O, but you can enable it to provide some limited support. Launch Windows Settings and click "Time & Language", then "Language", and then "Administrative language settings". In the window that appears, click the "Change system locale..." button. Check the "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" check box and then click the OK button. UTF-8 output support will now be enabled in Command Prompt for languages that use a single codepoint for characters (such as Spanish and Russian). Unfortunately while input for diacritical marks and non-Latin characters appear correctly when being entered, they do not appear to be correctly passed to CLIPS (as occurs when running CLIPS as a terminal application on macOS or Linux).